# Java Mail XML - Inserting variables into xml returned data

Tags: java, xml, email

So i have tried to write my problem as clear as possible in the title but i will elaborate on the situation. currently in java, i am trying to get information from a email template which i have created.

Once i have got the email data, i need to inject variables into different parts of the email content.

So for example i have 3 different email templates written in xml files. etemplate1.xml, etemplate2, etemplate3.

So far i am getting the information using the following code.

```
    String fm_subject = "";  // Formatted string of email subject
    String fm_bodytext = ""; // Formatted string of email body text
    String fm_bodytables = ""; // Formatted string of email body tables

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    org.w3c.dom.Document doc = dBuilder.parse(getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/"+requestType+".xml"));
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("emailtemplate");

        Node nNode = nList.item(0);

        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

            fm_subject = eElement.getElementsByTagName("subject").item(0).getTextContent();
            fm_bodytext = eElement.getElementsByTagName("bodytext").item(0).getTextContent();
            fm_bodytables = eElement.getElementsByTagName("bodytable").item(0).getTextContent();
```

**Note: requestType = the template which will be used**

**XML EMAIL TEMPLATE EXAMPLE:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<emailtemplates>
    <emailtemplate>
        <subject>
        subject information


        </subject>
        <bodytext>

        This is the  Body Text


        </bodytext>
        <bodytable>

        This Body Tables



        </bodytable>
    </emailtemplate>
</emailtemplates>
```

What i need to do is format the data i am getting back from the xml file, with variables. The problem is, i can't just add a variable to the end of the returned data.

Example  code:

user_id //Example variable

user_code //Example variable

```
fm_bodytext = eElement.getElementsByTagName("bodytext").item(0).getTextContent() + user_id + user_code;
```

This would append the variable always to the end of the body information. I need to add variables in between the xml element bodytext.

Here is a clear example in plain text of how i want it.

```
            <bodytext>

        This is the  Body Text

             hi user_id,  your code is user_code



        </bodytext>
```

Hopefully i have explained my problem well enough. If not please let me know and i wil try to clear up the issue.

Thanks !

Comment: You can get the text content from the node, use `String.replace()`, then remove the text nodes from the XML and add the replaced string in its place. Unfortunately W3C DOM being dumb as it is, this is probably somewhat annoying to do. I'd consider using JDOM, where you could use [`Element.getText()`](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/Element.html#getText()), [`Element.removeChildren()`](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/Element.html#removeContent()) and [`Element.addContent(String)`](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/) for these steps.

Comment: Thank you for the insight millimoose. I shall take into consideration your JDOM replacement and i will give it a try. I completely forgot about string.replace and this is perfect for what i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using XSLT to just render new XML from your template ? See http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/

example class:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import org.junit.Test;

public class XMLOutTest{

@Test
public void textXML() {
    String input = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<root><subject>my subject</subject><bodytext>my body text</bodytext>my body table<bodytable></bodytable></root>";
    try {
        StreamSource src = new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes()));
        StreamSource xslSrc = new StreamSource(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/xmltransform.xsl"));
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);

        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer t = factory.newTransformer(xslSrc);
        t.transform(src, result);

    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

your xsl-template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"></xsl:output>
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <emailtemplates>
            <emailtemplate>
                <subject>
                    <xsl:text>subject information</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="./subject"></xsl:value-of>
            </subject>
            <bodytext>
                <xsl:text>This is the Body Text</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="./bodytext"></xsl:value-of>
            </bodytext>
            <bodytable>
                <xsl:text>This Body Tables</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="./bodytable"></xsl:value-of>
            </bodytable>
        </emailtemplate>
    </emailtemplates>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!, I do believe this method would work as well. I have already managed to solve my issue using millimoose's suggestion. This is great information though if people need another method from the one i am using. I would suggest both to be viable answers to my question.